# Is it possible to access web viewer content in Filemaker Pro?

Tags: html, web, filemaker

I am developing Filemaker application that uses web viewer.

I need to access to DOM or Window object inside web viewer control so that I can send some messages(or trigger predefined events) to web page from Filemaker.

So the goal is to make web page inside web viewer control get some data that Filemaker sends at any time. Web page is a local html file of which URL starts with `file:///`.

Is it possible to do this or is there another way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to send a message from the web viewer to FileMaker using the fmp url protocol (which you can use to e.g. call a script in FileMaker from Javascript).

You can't send a message directly to the web viewer from FileMaker. Your best bet is to set a variable on a service somewhere and have the web viewer poll that service to see if the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

"This task" is not well-defined, IMHO. What exactly are "messages" or "predefined events"? You certainly *can* use the [Set Web Viewer script step](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref2.37.68.html#1076179) to make the web viewer load another URL at any time you wish to.

Note also that you can use [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to load data into the web-viewer directly, without requiring an external HTML document.